# How to remove strings in a sentence?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a homework that requires me to remove every random words in a sentence. For example when i type : `"Hello asjdasjdas my asdjasidj name kasdjas is asjdoaisd Felix sadads"` the output will remove the random words and it will be `"Hello my name is Felix"`. I have tried to detect the string using if, but i have no idea how to convert it to array to 2d so i can remove the string.

```
    int testcase;
    char kalimat[100];
    scanf("%d",&testcase);

    for(int i = 0; i < testcase; i++){
        scanf("%d",&length);
        scanf("%[^\n]",kalimat);

        for(int j = 0; j < length;j++){
            if(kalimat[j-1] == ' ' || kalimat[j+1] == ' ' ){
                // How to remove the string?
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: When `j` is 0 - what is `kalimat[j-1]` value?

Comment: you could try shifting left the substring : for(i='  ' until next '  ') kalimat[i]=kalimat[i+length of the word to be removed]. When you reach the end of the sentence,you fill with zeros what remains

Comment: `will remove the random words` - it looks like you removed every second word, not random. Is a `"Hello asjdasjdas"` also a valid output?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to convert it to 2d array you can do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char sentence[]="Hello World";
  char arr[2][20];
  int i,j,word;
  for(i=0,j=0,word=0;sentence[i]!='\0';i++){
    if(sentence[i]!=' ') {
      arr[word][j]=sentence[i];
      j++;
    }
    else{
      arr[word][j]='\0';
      word++; j=0;
    }
  }
  arr[word][j]='\0';
  printf("%s\n%s",arr[0],arr[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `strtok` you can tokenize a string (char array). Please note: the string is changed, so use a copy!
You can try something like this:

```
char string[] = "Hasta-la-vista-baby";
char delimiter[] = "-";
char *ptr = NULL;
bool bRandomWord = false;

//first token
ptr = strtok(string, delimiter);

while(ptr != NULL)
{
    printf("Found: %s\n", ptr);
    bRandomWord = Check(ptr); // you'll have to implement this
    if (!bRandomWord)
    {
        // you can copy ptr here to a char[][] using strcpy(_n)
    }
    // next tokens
    ptr = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
}
```